# Problems running MS Virtual Server/PC on virtualized Server 2003 (on VMWare ESX 3.5)

Tags: windows-server-2003, vmware-esx, virtualization

We have the following setup:

- A physical server running VMWare ESX 3.5
- There are two virtual machines on ESX: both running Windows Server 2003 SP2 (each have 3Gb of RAM and a physical CPU core)

I am now trying to establish a MS Virtual Server 2005 R2 on one of those virtualized servers to run development/test machines. However, I struck an issue - any virtual machine I try to run (on VS or VPC 2007) run **extremely** slowly. We are talking 10 minutes to get to the Windows loading screen for an XP virtual machine slow.

Has anyone tried doing this and if so then is there a magic trick that needs doing to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Has anyone tried doing this and if so then is there a magic trick that needs doing to make this happen?

The various virtualisation blogs from MS have tried this, and get the expected work: if the underlying hardware has CPUs with virtualisation extensions it works, but slowly. They do this to show the virtualised system is as capable as a real system.

One layer of virtualisation has a performance hit, two layers just multiplies this up.

Why not just create the test/dev VMs in VMWare and keep things much simpler and faster.

Comment: The only reason for making a MS virtual layer is because consultants around the office use MS virtualization on their machines so we'd like to make that easily compatible with the server deployment. 
But I guess we'll have to go through conversion and setting up access to the VMWare console. Thanks.

Comment: If there is enough demand, another server for Hyper-V shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Thanks. I gave VMWare Converter a go. It works after jumping through a few hoops... Just need to do a few more and then provide instructions to others.

Answer (score 0):

Yes lots of us have tried something similar but without exception it's a very bad idea indeed - very bad, "Miley-Cryus-suddenly-dressed-up-all-adult-bad" in fact.